# Same WordPress Website but Different Sub Domain for Mobile Version

Tags: wordpress, mobile

Let say I have WP website on mydomain.com, I'm using WP plugin [WP Smart Mobile](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsmart-mobile/) to automatically convert the website to mobile version depends on the devices. It works nicely, but I want to use sub domain m.mydomain.com rather than mydomain.com IF ONLY my website in mobile version. In short, m.mydomain.com and mydomain.com refer to the same website and database, m.mydomain.com address only display for mobile users. Is it possible to do? If yes, how?

Thanks for any enlightment for this case.

additional information: I'm using linux server with apache web server.

Comment: The answer to this question is "yes, it is possible."  But the how depends largely on what type of software your server is running.  Is it a linux server, running Apache? IIS on Windows? Etc.

Comment: thanks, i will edit the question and add some information, it's linux server and running apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I would use it is to create a virtual host for both the domain and the mobile subdomain (the vhost file goes in /etc/apache2/sites-available) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/document/root
    ServerName mydomain.com

   <Directory /var/www/path/to/document/root>
       AllowOverride all # allow overriding of options with .htaccess
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/document/root
    ServerName m.mydomain.com

   <Directory /var/www/path/to/document/root>
       AllowOverride all # allow overriding of options with .htaccess
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You will then need to enable the virtual host and restart apache.  How to do this can vary depending on which linux distro you are using.

Once the vhosts are set up, both the domain and the subdomain will point to the same website.  I'm assuming that your wordpress plugin can redirect mobile clients to the subdomain.

Update: You can use javascript to do the redirect, as long as you know that you are dealing with a mobile client.

```
var path = window.location.pathname,
    host = window.location.host,
    mobileVersion = 'http://m.' + host + path;

window.location = mobileVersion;
```

I also just had a thought, that the virtual host may be entirely unnecessary, as long as there is an A record for your subdomain.  Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks! now the problem is the wordpress plugin cannot redirect it automatically to the subdomain.

Comment: I updated my answer with some information about redirecting with javascript.